# PDF.js edit PDF by removing text

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf.js

Is it possible to remove a text from PDF using https://github.com/mozilla/pdfjs-dist ?

I would like to iterate over all of the texts and remove all of them

Comment: Dude, I'm not usually the one saying this, but please start by adding more details. What kind of pdf, are they images or can they be parsed, can you anticipate the input PDFs formats? Fix your title as well.

Comment: @Billybobbonnet Consider a PDF with images and texts (Selectable texts). I would like to remove all texts from PDF and keep anything else.